# I want to know about blogger template language

Tags: blogger, blogspot

i'm looking some syntax.

```
<b:includable id='main'>

<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
</b:loop>

</b:includable>
</b:widget>
</b:section>
<data:post.id/>

<b:if cond='data:post.dateHeader'>
</b:if>
```

This is mixed any programming language? I need to know this syntax language name? Who create this language? Where i find help about this syntax language? this language same as other programming language?

Tell me please? I can't found help about this language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find information on [Blogger Help.](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/)

See for example: [Widget Tags for Layouts](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?answer=46995)

Answer (score 5):

This: http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=42095 is a fairly comprehensive guide to all the relevant tags in Blogger's template language.